# undefined index 'user' when deleting

Tags: symfony, entity

using symfony 4.2.4, here is my method:

```
/**
     * @Route("/users/{id}/delete", name="delete_user", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function delete($id)
    {
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');

        $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $entityManager->getRepository(User::class)
            ->find($id);

        $entityManager->remove($user);
        $entityManager->flush();

        $this->addFlash('success', 'User successfully removed!');

        return $this->redirectToRoute('list_users');
    }
```

on the flush command I get "undefined index: users", but the very same method on other entities (not users) works like a charm. I don't get the point here, any hint?

thanks a lot

Comment: Can you show us your User entity ? as well as the entire error message ?

Comment: Although what im about to say wont fix the problem (since its valid code), i suggest you pass the user object to the delete method directly, to let the param converter query the user object. This will save you few lines of code here and there ! public function delete(User $user) and then you can directly remove($user) & flush().  (https://symfony.com/doc/master/best_practices/controllers.html#using-the-paramconverter)

Comment: The error is `undefined index: users` => user**s** . It's not appears to be about the remove action, you probably try to access to an `users` variable in a template or something like this.

Comment: here is my user entity:

https://codeshare.io/GbyXZV

thanks

Comment: check for duplicate URL or try clear cache

Answer (score 0):

It seems your code is perfectly correct. I believe error shouldn't come while flushing object. 
[Symfony Documement](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#deleting-an-object)

Answer (score 0):

I don't recommend to use method "GET" for delete "user". You can try to use this code:

```
    /**
 * @Route("/{id}", name="users_delete", methods="DELETE")
 */
public function delete(Request $request, $id): Response
{
    $idUser = $this->UsersRepository->findOneById($id);
    if ($this->isCsrfTokenValid('delete'.$idUser->getId(), $request->request->get('_token'))) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->remove($idUser);
        $em->flush();
    }
    return $this->redirectToRoute('users_index');
}
```